# Cancelling a CronSchedule workflow after allowing it to finish

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

If I have a workflow with Cronschedule specified with multiple activities, is there a way to cancel/terminate it only after all activities in the workflow have been executed. I also don't want it to have the ContinueAsNew status anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to cancel self as the last step in the workflow.
You can either use an activity to call the Cadence [API](https://github.com/uber-go/cadence-client/blob/b31c3bbfb06a1f96c6ad911a48237cfbc4f9a565/client/client.go#L159):

```
CancelWorkflow(ctx context.Context, workflowID string, runID string) error
```

or use [RequestCancel](https://github.com/uber-go/cadence-client/blob/b31c3bbfb06a1f96c6ad911a48237cfbc4f9a565/workflow/workflow.go#L199) feature.

```
func RequestCancelExternalWorkflow(ctx Context, workflowID, runID string) Future {
```

It's called `external` but if you put self workflowID, it should also work.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I originally tried calling CancelWorkflow externally using temporal's client.Client, but I'll try adding an activity at the end. If I add RequestCancelExternalWorkflow at the end of a workflow, how could I get it to not cancel until I want it to?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "get it to not cancel until I want it to"? I don't follow this

Comment: If I cancel self as the last step for a cron workflow, then wouldn't it always stop after the first run? Is there a way to have this last step cancellation to happen only when you signal it to (i.e. cancel externally)?

Comment: Then you just cancel it externally, wouldn't that work? I probably don't understand your question well.